# How to get # variable from the url path using php

Tags: php, mysql, json, url

i want to get variable called #test from url and i want to show json results from database

its showing wrong results,  this is the url am passing variable called #test like this

http://myinnos.in/read_all_filter_feed.php?filter=#test

this is my php code to get data from url and parsing JSON

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include("../db_config.php");
$linklist=array();
$link=array();

$filter=$_GET['filter'];

$percentage = "%";

$qr=mysql_query("
SELECT * from test where message LIKE '$percentage.$filter.$percentage'") or die(mysql_error());
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qr))
{
 $link['id']=$res['id'];
 $link['name']=$res['name'];
 array_push($linklist,$link);
}
//print_R($linklist);
echo json_encode($linklist);
?>
```

Comment: `#` denotes an URI fragment. It is never send to the server. Either URL encode the string or just don't use it in the url

Comment: am new to php please if u can please provide code to me ! thank you in advance

Comment: Did you (re)search any of the things I just commented about?

Comment: i tried encoding but in this case some time i want to sent @test or #test or test it is like that !! so if i decode exact # from the php code for remaining variables throws null values thats the problem